# Using Python3 itertools permutations: how can I specify all r > 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, permutation, python-itertools

I only want the permutations of a string that are of size 2 or more, so no empty set or set of one character. It seems `r` must be an int and I cannot say `r = range(2,N)` or `r>=2`. The only solution I can think of is a for-loop; is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do. The `r` argument is for specifying the exact length of the permutations that will be output. Do you want all permutations of all lengths? Something like `[permutations(iterable, r) for r in range(2,len(iterable)+1)]` maybe?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a for-loop is unavoidable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You do need a `for` loop. But you could do it more succinctly with `itertools.chain`, which would create a generator that yields first all permutations of length 2, then 3, etc.

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

lst = [1, 2, 3]
tuples_gen = chain(*(permutations(lst, i) for i in range(2, len(lst) + 1)))
```